# HyperLeder Fabric: Failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while starting chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have started to get time out error while installing my chaincode. The chaincode is pretty basic, in fact, I am just extending the fabcar node.js sample. Please see the error I receive:

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err Proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg failed to execute transaction e865662f96312f27ee8a221faba6893633498693408f95e57e5e404e58731afd: timeout expired while starting chaincode aar:1.0 for transaction e865662f96312f27ee8a221faba6893633498693408f95e57e5e404e58731afd

Error from the Peer node container logs:

> 2018-10-16 09:44:13.640 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 038 [mychannel][e865662f] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while starting chaincode aar:1.0 for transaction e865662f96312f27ee8a221faba6893633498693408f95e57e5e404e58731afd

I have already increased the values of the following two environment variables but to no avail:

> - CORE_CHAINCODE_DEPLOYTIMEOUT=1000s
> - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=1000s

Comment: can you confirm this is during installation or instantiation phase and which SDK and which chaincode?

Comment: I got the same, it is during instantiation

Answer (score 2):

For me there was a compilation error in a JS class inside the chaincode folder. So, ensure that everything inside your chaincode folder is fine, otherwise you'll get lscc timeout error while chaincode installs on the peer